# How can I give line break in excel epplus c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I am using **Epplus** library to convert `dataTable` in Excel. I am using   a textarea in my front end site. In which a line break is also there. But, the problem is when I convert this file to Excel, text shows in one line not with a line break.

How can I add a line break in Excel Epplus.

I am using the following script:

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile)) {
  ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Accounts");
  ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
  pck.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Did you to turn on text wrap on the cells?  It is off by default.  So something like this:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <textarea id="TextArea1" style="height: 200px; width: 400px;" runat="server"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_OnClick" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this:

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create the table from the textbox
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1");

    var dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = TextArea1.InnerText;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    var excelDocName = @"c:\temp\temp.xlsx";
    var aFile = new FileInfo(excelDocName);

    if (aFile.Exists)
        aFile.Delete();

    var pck = new ExcelPackage(aFile);
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
    ws.Cells["A1:A2"].Style.WrapText = true;  //false by default
    pck.Save();
    pck.Dispose();

}
```

And I drop this in the textarea:

```
This is line 1.

This is line 3.

This is line 5.
```

Which opens with line breaks shown.

Answer (score 4):

`.LoadFromDataTable()` will preserve linebreaks that exist in the data in `dataTable`.

Running this minimal example produces a spreadsheet where the string in cell A2 contains the line break:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("TestCol");
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["TestCol"] = "string that"+Environment.NewLine+"contains a linebreakc";
dt.Rows.Add(row);

using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DataTable");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

    package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\test.xlsx"));
}
```

I'd  guess either the data doesnt contain a linebreak or its just a case that you can only see one line when you open the spreadsheet because of the row height?

Comment: +1 This works but it does not automatically format the cells so that the text is displayed properly.(just caveat emptor)

Comment: Chad is right, for visual purposes this solution does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this solution:

```
string textOriginal = "First line text.| Second line text.";
string textToWrite = textOriginal.Replace("|", ("" + ((char)13) + ((char)10)));

myWorksheet.Cells["a1"].Value = textToWrite;
```